# Discord bot - DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

As I said in a previous post of mine, I am quite new to creating discord bots and am using Discord.js. This time I am having DiscordAPIError[50035]. From what it looks like, it stems from a problem with scopes and authorization regarding the bot as I am getting:

`{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}`

The URL has the error which occurs in the terminal.

[Terminal Error](https://sourceb.in/aaZrvCnIj6)

It can also be due to something wrong with my installation of the /@discordjs/rest/ module as prevalent in this part of the error:

```
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (*:\Users\*\Desktop\***Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:667:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (*:\Users\*\Desktop\***Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:464:14)
    at async REST.request (*:\Users\*\Desktop\***Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:910:22) {
```

Ì have tried looking at different posts with no luck.

Edit:

[Index.js](https://sourceb.in/rqi8RTCbXd)

[Play.js](https://sourceb.in/UVNqCp3ozy)

[Skip.js](https://sourceb.in/5cBVDlSdsq)

[Pause.js](https://sourceb.in/Ljblyxdkav)

[Resume.js](https://sourceb.in/hYqnO1fSe6)

[Queue.js](https://sourceb.in/ILZZmx8wDr)

[Exit.js](https://sourceb.in/iZku8jL8tn)

Comment: Could you please show the code? I can't determine the issue without the code.

Comment: As @Kārlis Kazāks said, please show us your code. We can't really help you without it.

Comment: Since the code is split into different files, would you like me to show my index.js or something else?

Comment: @JommyTest if the answer i posted doesn't solve your issue please post the `index.js` file. If the file is too big you can post a pastebin link to it.

Comment: I have updated the post to include index.js

Comment: `name` fields are missing

Comment: @JommyTest sorry i meant to say. "... please post the command file"

Comment: @KārlisKazāks, I have updated with the corresponding commands

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of googling it looks like your `rest.put(...)` in your ready event is the error line. You can try the following;

1. According to the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration) you don't need to register globally like you're doing. It is also highly discouraged as you're mapping all guild ids from the cache, which may be outdated. To register globally you can simply do this:

```
await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
    { body: commands },
);
```

or, to register guild commands:

```
await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
    { body: commands },
);
```

2. Upgrade to REST version 10

If this still doesn't the error is most likely coming from one of your commands, please debug and tell us which if that is the case.